# How can I only DM users with a certain role in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the bot to dm to members having a certain role so i tried this,

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def message_role(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message):
    for member in ctx.message.server.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await member.send(member, message)
```

It doesn't work actually and I also don't want my bot to be flagged for spamming so I want a check or something so that the bot will only dm if the role has 25 or below 25 members. If the role have more than 25 users it should return and say something like - "Can't dm this much users".
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of `role.members`

```py
@bot.command()
async def message_role(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message):
    if not len(role.members) <= 25:
        return await ctx.send("Can't dm this much users")
    for i in role.members:
        await i.send(message)
```